# IIS server error while loading a web application

Tags: iis, iis-express

I am having trouble in loading a project. Initially this use to work fine until today. (after someone committed some code and i updated my solution)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

open the csproj file and change false to true for  UseIISExpress.

< UseIISExpress > true < /UseIISExpress >